# is using ion slide inside ion segment a good approach

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

In my project I am tasked to create a scrollable filter buttons for a list. I was thinking to use either `ion-slides` or `ion-segment`, but using ion-slides gives me no option for segment changing, while `ion-segment` does not fit the requirement on the design (3.5 buttons showed before scrolling, accurate margins). Therefore I come up with this:

```
<ion-segment scrollable="true" (ionChange)="segmentChange($event)">
      <ion-slides [options]="slideOption">
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-segment-button class="buttonActive" value="a">A</ion-segment-button>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-segment-button class="button" value="b">B</ion-segment-button>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-segment-button class="button" value="c">C</ion-segment-button>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <ion-segment-button class="button" value="d">D</ion-segment-button>
        </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
    </ion-segment>
```

I am wondering if my approach is correct or there are a simpler solution. This method also gives me a problem of unable to create padding inside the `ion-segment` (I tried putting `ion-label` inside but cannot create whitespace so that the text become more centered)

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your button in down line. Close on the same line.

Comment: apologies, visual studio format document does that